# Claiming winter wear

Tags: ethics, expenses

I currently live in a tropical country and would need to travel to a colder place (5 degree Celcius) for business. So I have to buy winter wear to survive the cold weather and it cost quite a lot. Is it ok to ask my boss if I could claim these expense provided the company policies allow? I am asking here to solve the ethical dilemma and wish not to sound a free rider to my boss.

Comment: This sounds _very_ company policy specific.  You can ask, but only your employer can answer your question.

Comment: But it also sounds _very_ reasonable. People generally understand winter jackets and clothing are expensive.

Comment: Have you ever heard of on-line shopping?

Comment: @saaahu yes I have. But I do not prefer them for clothes for obvious reasons

Comment: Would you care to explain the _obvious reasons_?

Comment: @scaaahu I feel comfortable buying after trying for size issues

Comment: Let me put it this way. I don't care where and how you buy the winter wear, but your boss would. Suppose it costs $300 to get one from local store. If it cost $150 + $50 (for delivery cost), which means the total cost is $200. If I were your boss, I would certainly ask why don't you buy it on-line?

Comment: I guess you haven't tried buying on-line recently. Also, you boss would not care if the size  doesn't fit too well as long as it would get you warm.

Comment: I am glad you aren't :)

Comment: Don't forget you want your boss pay for it. You would have to care for the cost.

Comment: 5 Celsius is not that cold.  You just need a jacket and cap.  Look used.   Can you borrow?

Comment: Since I can't answer, I'll comment: Just tell your boss "*I don't have any winter clothes and wouldn't ever use it here, what's my budget to get some on that business trip so I don't freeze to death?*". By asking for a budget in advance there's no ethics issue. It even gives them the opportunity to say "Zero". Keep in mind you can wear 2 t-shirts under a long sleeved shirt.

Comment: @Peter Certainly. I have gone ahead and done that. To me it is not totally unreasonable.

Answer (score 8):

While this is going to be very company specific, you can check yourself against a checklist to see if you think a reasonable employer would consider the purchase of winter wear to be appropriate for an employee to claim.

- Is my job requiring me to be *outside* in the colder weather, or will I be working in an office?  If the answer is no, then you can probably stop now.
- Is the temperature so cold as to be out in it is actively dangerous.  Think Canada in winter, which is *considerably* colder than 5 degrees.  Here in Australia, which is a temperate climate, 5 degrees is a cold winter's day.
- If I were considering travelling to a cooler country for personal reasons such as a holiday, would I consider the cost of purchasing the clothes a barrier to going?  If the company provided the clothes, would you then go?

Ethics and morals for what you can and can't claim can be a battleground of opinion, but it boils down to: "If I didn't *need* this to do my job, why should my company pay for it?"

Comment: sounds reasonable, as for expensive, I live in the tropics and cold weather gear is very very cheap if you're willing to go the second hand route because there's very little demand. So I have some pretty expensive and durable cold weather clothing for trips which cost me peanuts. I wear them to Sydney when I go which is cold for me :) But I have even heavier gear for NZ trips.